# How to return back only specific pixels

Tags: function, matlab, call

I wrote this function in `matlab` that sets the value of the pixels `x` that have a degree of membership `y` = `1` to `1` as follows:

```
   function c = core(x, y)
            for i=1:length(y)
            for j=1:length(y)
                if y(i,j) == 1
                x(i,j) = 1;
                end
            end
            end
            c=x
       end
```

As you can see, the whole modified image is returned back. But, what I'm interested in is only those pixels that were modified to `1`. What modification(s) should I do to the function in order to get back only those pixels?

Thanks.

Comment: why repost the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011743/setting-pixels-to-a-specific-value/15012061#15012061 ?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the [find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) command. You can get the linear index or [row,col] indices.

```
ind = find(y == 1);
[row,col]= find(y == 1);
```